# Envio de notifcaciones desde vs c# usando firebase

Tags: c#, firebase

Soy nuevo en el aprendizaje de Firebase cluod messaging , tengo una app desarrollada en android studio configurada para recibir notificaciones fcm, hasta aqui todo bien, desde la consola de firebase envio mensajes y son recibidos sin problema.
Por otro lado necesito que en una aplicacion de consola o winform de visual studio c# o vb.net 
tambien poder enviar notificaciones via fcm , esto es lo que no logro realizar
existen librerias "Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-Net" del paquete nuget pero no las se usar, no existe o no encuentro documentacion respaldatoria para su uso.
El codigo mas cercano para q ande lo encontre en stack y es el siguiente

```
  try
        {
            var applicationID = "AAAAjPPCpVE:APA9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var senderId = "605385041233";
        string deviceId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var data = new
        {
            to = deviceId,
            notification = new
            {
                body = "This is the message Body",
                title = "This is the title of Message",
                icon = "myicon"
            },
            priority = "high"

        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        //Response.Write(sResponseFromServer);

                        textBox1.Text=sResponseFromServer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox1.Text=(ex.Message);
    }


}

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
```

Esto me devuelve el error

```
{"multicast_id":5407675484915313566,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MissingRegistration"}]}.
```

y calculo yo q con este codigo me esta faltando el token o alguna autorizacion.

Algun ejemplo q funcione? o una solucion para mi codigo?

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estas llamando al servicio correctamente pero el pedido esta mal formado, la estructura debería ser:

```
{
  "to": "<id del receptor>",
  "data": {
    "message": "Hola mundo!",
   }
}
```

por lo que veo estas incluyendo el campo `to` dentro de `data` y por eso no te reconoce el ID que estas enviando.

Comment: es modificado mi codigo y sigo sin poder resolverlo te envio la modificacion para que dentro de tus posibilidades puedas seguir ayudandome:

Comment: WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new

            {
               to= "",
                notification = new
                {
    
                body = "great match!",
                title = "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                icon = "myicon"
    }
          };
me devuelve el mismo error {"multicast_id":6903892854529210823,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MissingRegistration"}]}

Comment: Agrego una inquietud mas a mis desconocimiento, el campo "to" que deberia ser el token es obligatorio? dado que mi interes es mandar el mensaje a todos los dispositivos

Comment: @JuanBorio no se puede mandar directamente a todos los dispositivos, se puede mandar a un dispositivo, a un grupo ( teniendo los ids) y a un tema (al que los dispositivos deben suscribirse) en tu caso podrías poner un tema general y suscribir a todos los usuarios entonces simplemente mandas un mensaje a ese tema para llevar a todos los dispositivos.